# Finding the longest line of a document

Tags: windows, text-search

I am looking for a program that can find the longest line of a `.txt` file. It should run on Microsoft Windows. Any license or price is fine.

Comment: How many characters shall a tab count? Just 1, 4 or 8 or customizable?

Comment: @Walmart - I think that your answers above should be put into an answer rather than left as comments.

Answer (score 5):

> **I am looking for a program that can find the longest line of a .txt file. It should run on Microsoft Windows.**

I've listed two *FREE* solutions below that may suffice for your need.

### Method 1

You could use: `wc -L "c:\folder\file.txt"` from the [CoreUtils for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm) for example if you just need the number of the length of the longest line in that file. This would be a freebie too by the way.

---

### Method 2

You can do this in Windows with [PowerShell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerShell) as well for a particular file:

1. Get the maximum length number of a record in a file:

   `GC "c:\folder\file.txt" | Measure -Property length -Maximum | Select Maximum`
2. Get the content of the longest line/record in a file

   `GC "c:\folder\file.txt" | Sort -Property length | Select -last 1`

---

### Further Resources

- [Get-Content](http://ss64.com/ps/get-content.html)
- [Select-Object](http://ss64.com/ps/select-object.html)
- [Measure-Object](http://ss64.com/ps/measure-object.html)
- [Sort-Object](http://ss64.com/ps/sort-object.html)

Comment: I would like to mention that if the file contains CTL language scripts like Devanagari, then use following command:

GC "c:\folder\file.txt" -Encoding UTF8 | Sort -Property length | Select -last 1

Answer (score 0):

You can add an extension to `Notepad++` to perform this operation.  See [this answer on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/1170431/how-can-i-see-which-line-is-the-longest-a-document-with-notepad/1170461#1170461) for details